# Ubuntu nstallation partition manager

Tags: partitioning, system-installation

I want to install Ubuntu instead of Windows, but I want to save files which are on another (not windows-root) partitions. So what do I do? Something else->select my windows root partition->and?..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's correct, you will want to select "Something else", select your windows partition (or other partitions you want to modify) and change its size (reduce it) by however large you want the new Ubuntu install to be.

Once you apply that resize, you can then create a partition in that free space for Ubuntu and "use it for" / (root).

You may also want to create a swap partition and "use it for" swap. The usual recommendation is to size it to 2X your RAM if you intend on using hibernate.

Comment: Thanks for help. Also I have another internal HDD which I use as storage for media and so on. What mount point should I choose for it?

Comment: You can usually just ignore it in the install and Ubuntu will detect it and add it for you automatically as an additional drive. It should show up on your desktop and in the file manager. If not, it can be mounted manually in a number of ways after the fact. I'd err on the side of caution and ignore it until you get the system installed and booting.